# What can I do to make node/npm/related commands send their output back to the terminal I used to launch them?

Tags: node.js

What can I do to make node/npm/related commands send their output back to the terminal I used to launch them?

I've recently installed NodeJS 10.4.2 on Windows 10. When I run any node or npm command from PowerShell, Git Bash, or the Node terminal shortcut, a new window is opened, the output is directed there, and the window is closed. I feel like there must be a setting I've flipped under a previous installation, but I can't find it, and it's making me bananas.

Comment: Have you integrated these terminals with any IDE or Editor?

Comment: Yes, and PowerShell works with IntelliJ, but that's it. VS Code doesn't work with either terminal, and Git Bash doesn't work with IntelliJ.